# Meteor 503 from CollectionFS

Tags: meteor, proxy, upload, collectionfs

I got a 503 when trying to upload using the CollectionFS Filesystem adaptor (only on production, local works fine.)
the response headers show:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://meteor.local
```

I would like to know what this address is, but I could not find documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

Few thing that come to mind:

- Your static files URL under the web server.

  - Do you set it to a virtual directory (location) on your web server?
    If yes, check your nginx/apache virtual directory directives. Make sure there are correct
  - Do you handle it in your meteor application?
    If you set it to your meteor application, did you set the route for it in your application correctly?
- Permission issues between the user that run the web-server, the user that run the meteor application and the user that own the actual folder on the file system